# Why is OpenSSH server installed and enabled by default?

Tags: ssh, debian, openssh, linux-distributions

I am installing a new Debian based distro. I'm following a guide and it appears that OpenSSH server is enabled by default. That is, `openssh-server` is installed by default. To my understanding, this is a Daemon that allows remote access to my machine.

This seems like a security hazard because it increases the attack surface. A hacker can try to SSH into my machine. I don't think I will ever want to SSH into this machine. Why is this enabled by default? And how do I disable it

Comment: If you'll never access that machine remotely you can disable the OpenSSH service with `sudo systemctl disable ssh.service`. People heavily rely on SSH and OpenSSH by itself is not a security risk. However a lack of hardening and bad security practices are.

Comment: @megamorf Thanks for the comment. I won't use openssh-server but I will SSH into other machines using openssh-client.

Comment: @newuser - So disable the OpenSSH Server daemon (sshd) instead. However, OpenSSH client doesn't require a service, so ssh.service would be OpenSSH Server not the OpenSSH client.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks. What is the command for this?

Comment: @newuser - Have you tried looking it up?

Comment: @newuser The command I posted earlier does exactly that - it disables the SSH service while still allowing you to use the openssh-client.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because some users set up computers as ‘headless’ machines (no display or keyboard). In that case, it’s difficult to use the computer without some form of remote access.

If you are setting up your machine with a display and keyboard, you can turn off the SSH server, as others have suggested. But if it’s a headless machine, it’s obviously impossible to turn *on* the SSH server.

Comment: Thanks for the note! Let me know if you have other security tips for hardening.